# Can you force activerecord associations to update without saving them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I have a couple models which are associated with the `has_many` `belongs_to` pair.  For the sake of demonstration, a client has one server but a server has many clients.  I might do something like this:

```
client1.server = the_server
client2.server = the_server
client3.server = the_server
```

My actual application is quite a bit more complex than this, but the example will work for illustration.

I want to inspect the associations between these objects before I save them.  ActiveRecord doesn't update their information until they are saved though.  In the example above, `the_server` has no idea who `client1`, `client2`, or `client3` are until one of them gets saved.  I'm sure that this helps active_record's efficiency, but it leaves model instances in memory in an inconsistent state.

Is there anything I can call on the clients or on the server that will cause them to update their states?

Comment: 3 and a half years latter and I have the same problem, but in my case the models can became inconsistent.

Anything to add?

Answer (score 1):

Call `#reload` on the objects to update them.

Comment: This requires the objects be saved first doesn't it?  reload says get the info from the db again.  If client1,2 and 3 are not saved their is nothing to reload.

Comment: That is my understanding, as well.  I don't want to refresh from the DB - quite the opposite:  I want the objects to refresh as though they had been saved.

Comment: This is a HUGE anti-pattern that indicates the modeling has issues.  use `clear_association_cache` if you want an object to reload associated objects because current associations are stale.  reloading itself can sometimes create infinite loops and also tends to be called 5 times in one request because "you just aren't sure" if the object has been reloaded depending on the controller/model your are currently in in your code

Comment: -1 because the OP asked for a solution that works without saving to the DB. `#reload` is only meaningful if the data was saved to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you start off like this:

```
client1 = the_server.clients.build(:name => 'a client', ...)
```

Then you should get what you're looking for I think.

EDIT:

Oops, I re-read your post and realized that `the_server` hasn't been saved yet either.  In that case perhaps:

```
client1.server = the_server
the_server.clients << client1
```

(be aware that this will save client1 if the_server is already saved)

or:

```
the_server.clients.build(:name => 'some client', ..., :server => the_server)
```

A bit redundant so perhaps there's a better way out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the reverse way of creating the association, then you are able to look at the models prior to them being saved:

```
the_server.clients << client1
the_server.clients << client2
the_server.clients << client3
```

Note, however, that you can only call `client1.server` immediately after if `the_server` already exists.